# How can I use BottomNavigationBar with BLoC?

Tags: dart, flutter

When I use `BottomNavigationBar` with BLoC pattern, it causes the error, `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`

I may listen a stream of a BLoC at just one place.

My code is the following.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bottom_tab_bloc/app_state_bloc.dart';
import 'package:bloc_provider/bloc_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      creator: (context, _bag) => AppStateBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String activeTab = "tab1";
  final bottomTabs = ["tab1", "tab2"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(activeTab),
      ),
      body: buildTab(activeTab),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomTabs.indexOf(activeTab),
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            activeTab = bottomTabs[index];
          });
        },
        items: bottomTabs.map((tab) =>
          buildBnbItem(tab)
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTab(String tab) {
    if (tab == "tab1") {
      return TabOne();
    } else if (tab == "tab2") {
      return TabTwo();
    }
  }

  BottomNavigationBarItem buildBnbItem (String tab) {
    assert(bottomTabs.contains(tab));

    if (tab == "tab1") {
      return BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Tab1'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one),
      );
    } else if (tab == "tab2") {
      return BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: Text('Tab1'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two),
      );
    }
  }
}

class TabOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppStateBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<AppStateBloc>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.outValue1,
      builder: (context, snapshot) =>
        Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.toString())),
    );
  }
}

class TabTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppStateBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<AppStateBloc>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.outValue2,
      builder: (context, snapshot) =>
        Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```

app_state_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc_provider/bloc_provider.dart';

class AppStateBloc implements Bloc {
  StreamController<int> _value1Controller
    = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get _inValue1 => _value1Controller.sink;
  Stream<int> get outValue1 => _value1Controller.stream;

  StreamController<int> _updateValue1Controller
    = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get updateValue1 =>
      _updateValue1Controller.sink;

  StreamController<int> _value2Controller
  = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get _inValue2 => _value2Controller.sink;
  Stream<int> get outValue2 => _value2Controller.stream;

  StreamController<int> _updateValue2Controller
  = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get updateValue2 =>
      _updateValue2Controller.sink;

  AppStateBloc(){
    _inValue1.add(1);
    _updateValue1Controller.stream.listen(_updateValue1);
    _inValue2.add(2);
    _updateValue2Controller.stream.listen(_updateValue2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _value1Controller.close();
    _updateValue1Controller.close();
    _value2Controller.close();
    _updateValue2Controller.close();
  }

  void _updateValue1(int value1) {
    _inValue1.add(value1);
  }

  void _updateValue2(int value2) {
    _inValue2.add(value2);
  }
}
```

I can go to the `TabTwo` from `TabOne` only at the first time, but the error occurs when I go back to `TabOne` .

I also tried using `StreamController<int>.broadcast()` in `app_state_bloc.dart`, but `snapshot.data` is always `null`.

- How can I implement `BottomNavigationBar` with BLoC pattern?
- Why the streams are called more than twice, though I write each stream at just one place?
- Is `AppStateBloc.dispose()` is called in this code? When and where `AppStateBloc.dispose()` is called?
- Why broadcast stream's `snapshot.data` is always null?

Answer (score 2):

> Why the streams are called more than twice, though I write each stream
>   at just one place?

The error is related to the number of subscribers to the stream. `StreamController` by default only allows one subscriber. That's why `TabOne` works fine the first time, but breaks afterwards.

> Is AppStateBloc.dispose() is called in this code? When and where
>   AppStateBloc.dispose() is called?

It would be called when the `BlocProvider` widget gets removed, but since it's being used as the app root, I guess this only happens when the app is closed.

> Why broadcast stream's snapshot.data is always null?

Broadcast streams do not buffer events when there is no listener. Since you're writing to the stream before `TabOne` is created, the event is lost and you get `null`.

> How can I implement BottomNavigationBar with BLoC pattern?

I guess it depends on your use case, but for this particular example, if you replace `StreamController` with [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart)'s [BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html), it works fine, because then you'd have a broadcast stream that always sends you the last event.